# c++17 filesystem, concat multiple strings

Tags: c++, stl, c++17, filesystems, std

this code

```
std::filesystem::path = std::filesystem::current_path();
(((path += "str1") += "str2") += "str3");
```

looks so messy. How do I add multiple strings to a path while not cluttering my code with all those brackets? Maybe a variadic function, similar to this?

```
path.concat("str1", "str2", "str3");
```

Comment: Do `str1`, `str2` and `str3` represent parts of the name of a file, or are they subdirectories, so you're building a path below the current directory?

Comment: I am trying to add extra information to a filename. I understand your question, if it were subdirectories, those can be appended using  /  directory separator

Comment: `path += (std::string("str1") + "str2" + "str3")`?

Answer (score 3):

You could easily create a helper function template containing a fold expression on the `,` operator:

```
template<class ...Args>
void concat(std::filesystem::path& p, Args&&...args)
{
    ((p += std::forward<Args>(args)), ...);
}
```

```
concat(path, "str1", "str2", "str3");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to output paths you might want to put an extra '/' between each string too.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

template<typename... args_t>
std::string concat(const std::string& path, char seperator, args_t&&... args)
{
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << path;

    // add a seperator before each arg
    ((os << seperator << std::forward<args_t>(args)), ...);

    return os.str();
}

int main()
{
    std::string path{ "path" };
    auto full_path = concat(path, '/', "str1", "str2", "str3");
    std::cout << full_path;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If they wanted to just add path elements that's built into `std::filesystem`, you can just do `path /= "str1" / "str2" / "str3"`

Comment: @AlanBirtles Check ;)

Comment: ok, `/=` doesn't work with multiple elements but you can still do it with `path = path / "str1" / "str2" / "str3"` https://godbolt.org/z/977f5cv6s or `path = std::filesystem::path{ "str1" } / "str2" / "str3"`